# Quick way to add code

Tags: support

I find it awfully tedious adding 4 spaces to every line, does anyone have any tricks they would like to share?

```
code
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select the code and click the “Code Sample” button [image: <code><$></code>] or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.